# Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined in NextJs, I'm facing this issue whenever I start server after installing any packages or simply 'npm i'

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, next.js, config

Reference snapshot of error -->>
[Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined, error in nextJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xfDG.png)

whenever I installs package or simply doing `npm i` I face this issue, I have tried

`//next.config.js module.exports = withPlugins([...], {webpack5: false,})` and `yarn add --dev webpack@webpack-4 less less-loader@5`

but none of them solved the issue later on digging on issue came to know that `@zeit\next-css` have been deprecated, below is the next.config.js reference please let me know how to resolve issue, how to update code in config file so that I can use built-in CSS support of nextJs itself leaving behind the deprecated one, Very very Thanks in Advance.

```js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    webpack: (config) => {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      };
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 1000000,
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 1000000,
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      module.exports = {
        resolve: {
          alias: {
            TweenLite: path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js'),
            TweenMax: path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js'),
            TimelineLite: path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js'),
            TimelineMax: path.resolve('node_modules', 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js'),
            ScrollMagic: path.resolve('node_modules', 'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js'),
            'animation.gsap': path.resolve(
              'node_modules',
              'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js'
            ),
            'debug.addIndicators': path.resolve(
              'node_modules',
              'scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js'
            )
          }
        }
      };
      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: `@zeit/next-sass` and `@zeit/next-css` have been deprecated. Next.js has built-in support for CSS/Sass since version 9.3, there's no need to use additional plugins for it.